# Python Bokeh Hover Tool giving: AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'tooltips' to Figure

Tags: python, bokeh

**How do I implement "tooltips" for the hover tool in Bokeh 0.12.11 (and possibly other versions)?**

Searching for "Bokeh hover tooltips" gives a bunch of documentation results such as:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html

But when I try to implement the "tooltips" on Bokeh 0.12.11 from an example such as:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/elements.html

I get the following error:
`AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'tooltips' to Figure, possible attributes are above, aspect_scale, etc.`

Comment: Although self-answering your questions are welcome here, please provide your solution as an answer to your question. With that said, what exactly is your question anyways?

Comment: If you have a good question that has no answer here you can ask and answer your own question, but you shouldn't answer IN the question

Comment: Apologies for not posing a proper question, I guess it was implied in the preamble.

Comment: I wasn't aware that that was proper on this site. I'll do that next time. Thanks

Comment: Can you do it *this* time? As a maintainer of Bokeh, having unanswered questions on SO is actually a burden for me and others. It will only take you a few moments to post a proper answer, and it will help other users.

Comment: Tho I should add, your conclusion is not quite right. The error you are seeing about `tooltips` and `Figure` is because the ability to pass `tooltips` to Figure was added in `0.13` but you are running `0.12.11`. You should always refer to the documentation and examples for the version you are actually running, if it is not the latest.

Comment: Hi bigreddot! Of course. I'll try to clean up the post. I'm enjoying bokeh! I realize now that those examples and documentation are for v0.13. At the time it wasn't clear to me. I'm unfamiliar with bokeh but not to programming/development. It would have helped if there was an icon/label with the minimum version requirement i.e. >=0.13.

Answer (score 7):

Solution:

I removed the TOOLTIP= [] declaration, and the tooltips= parameter in the figure() object.

Make the Hover Tool programatically and attach to Figure:

```
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

{ some code }

p = figure(tools=TOOLS, title=TITLE, x_axis_label='Pressure (mTorr)', y_axis_label='Roughness (nm)')

hover = HoverTool()

hover.tooltips = [
    ("Sample", "@names"),
    ("Pressure", "@x_values mTorr"),
    ("Roughness", "@y_values nm"),
]

p.tools.append(hover)
```

As pointed out here:
[Python Bokeh HoverTool formatters error: "unexpected attribute 'formatters' to HoverTool"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855928/python-bokeh-hovertool-formatters-error-unexpected-attribute-formatters-to-h)

version 0.12.11 supports it but I was having trouble implementing it.

Thanks to bigreddot for pointing out that passing that parameter only works in 0.13.